# Get data from Access given only the primary key of the Table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So I have a question regarding data referencing in Access using VBA and SQL. I have a table in my dataset with like 50 columns, and I need to make a query that a user can run that will manipulate the data in like 30 of these columns with a not-so straightforward algorithm. So the query will prompt the user for the primary key and then run a vba function for getting the value that the user wants, I was just wondering if it was possible that It could be done like this

```
SELECT Hardware_Type,
       Func32(Hardware_Type)
FROM Table1
WHERE (([Hardware_Type]) = [Hardware_Type]);
```

where `Hardware_type` is the primary key and `Func32` is a Visual Basic Function.

So now `Func32` only takes `Hardware_type` as an Input but needs to use 30 pieces of Data that are in the Row of that specific `Hardware_Type`. I just need to know that does there exist a way to do this and if there does, I would request a hint, because I really don't want to type in 30 different fields in the query and the function. Oh, and all of this is in Microsoft Access!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Just to be clear regarding the comments to the since-deleted answer to this question: Your `Func32` VBA function needs to make use of 30-odd fields in the specified row as part of its calculations but it only needs to return a single (scalar) value. Is that correct?

Comment: @GordThompson   Yes thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid passing a whole bunch of parameters to your VBA function but it will cost you one database hit for each time the function is called (i.e., once per row in the query that calls the function). Your function could do something like:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function Func32(HardwareType As String) As Variant
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sql As String

    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    sql = ""
    sql = sql & "PARAMETERS prmHardwareType TEXT(255);"
    sql = sql & "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Hardware_Type=[prmHardwareType]"
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("", sql)

    ' assign the PK argument as the query parameter and open it as a Recordset
    qdf!prmHardwareType = HardwareType
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

    ' do your calculations and assign the return value to the function name
    Func32 = rst!Field1 + rst!Field2 + rst!Field3

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Wow that cleared alot my confusion up, but I still have one question regarding what the cost exactly is, what do you mean by that it will cost me one database hit each time the function is run

Comment: @ManikSin The calling query would presumably have immediate access to the ~30 "other" fields itself, but if it only passes the Primary Key value to the VBA function then that function has to submit its own request to the database engine so it can find out what those ~30 "other" values are.

Comment: Ahh that makes alot of sense now! Thank you so much!!